# Ignore keys for null values when sending a post request with react and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am new to JS and I am trying to not include the keys which are null when sent with metadata. Foe ex I should not send tags and owner as they are null but send only filepath as it has value. How can I achieve this?

```
const metadata = {
        filepath: file.name,
        tags: [''],
        owner: '',

    };

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('metadata', JSON.stringify(metadata));

    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/fileUpload', formData, {
        onUploadProgress: (event) => {
       
            }));
        },
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tags key is array. You can remove those with the use of filter method.

```
const removeEmptyKeys = (data) => {
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    if ((data[key] === '' || data[key] == null || data[key].length === 0)) {
      delete data[key];
    }
   if (Array.isArray(data[key]) && data[key].filter(i => i.trim() !=="").length==0){
      delete data[key]  
    }
  });
};
```

and feel free to study about js truthy and falsy concept.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way

```
const removeEmptyKeys = (data) => {
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    if ((data[key] === '' || data[key] == null || data[key].length === 0)) {
      delete data[key];
    }
  });
};
```

Then call the function just before supplying the metadata

```
removeEmptyKeys(metadata);

formData.append('metadata', JSON.stringify(metadata));
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for helping @iphonic. But I am not able to remove tags: [''] (empty tags) in metadata.